# Adding missing date records in the time series data table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with a table which has data for weekdays. The data is pretty much about daily end of the day balance. The data looks like this:

```
ID  Name        Some Val    Other Val   Date

10  Somebody    33001.93    33001.93    2018-10-01
10  Somebody    33481.93    33481.93    2018-10-02
10  Somebody    33001.93    33001.93    2018-10-03
10  Somebody    33582.76    33582.76    2018-10-04
10  Somebody    33582.73    33582.79    2018-10-05
------- Missing row for 2018-10-06 ---------------
------- Missing row for 2018-10-07 ---------------
10  Somebody    33582.76    33582.76    2018-10-08
------- Missing row for 2018-10-09 ---------------
10  Somebody    33462.76    33462.76    2018-10-10
```

My task is to calculate average daily balance (total balance at end of each day/ total number of days). To get to that calculation, I need to ensure that I've data for all the days. To do that, the last available row needs to replace the missing data.

My need is this:

```
ID  Name        Some Val    Other Val   Date

10  Somebody    33001.93    33001.93    2018-10-01
10  Somebody    33481.93    33481.93    2018-10-02
10  Somebody    33001.93    33001.93    2018-10-03
10  Somebody    33582.76    33582.76    2018-10-04
10  Somebody    33582.73    33582.79    2018-10-05    
10  Somebody    33582.73    33582.79    2018-10-06
10  Somebody    33582.73    33582.79    2018-10-07    
10  Somebody    33582.76    33582.76    2018-10-08
10  Somebody    33382.76    33582.76    2018-10-09
10  Somebody    33462.76    33462.76    2018-10-10
```

Essentialy, the row 5 is written into missing rows 6 and 7 and row 8 gets written into row 9.

I got the solution partially, if it were only the missing weekend records.

```
select ID, Name, val1, val2, date from t
union all
select id, name, val1, val2, date + interval 1 day from t where dayofweek(date) = 6
union all
select id, name, val1, val2, date + interval 2 day from t where dayofweek(date) = 6
;
```

This partial solution works on the assumption that only the weekend records are missing. Two new tables are created by copying over data from Friday to Saturday and Sunday. Finally all three datasets are joined together.

The solutions fails if the data is missing from within the work week (e.g. a public holiday) so only rows 6 and 7 get filled. The row 9 still remains empty.

How do I find the missing records, fill them up with last record information and thus complete the time series? I am new to SQL but not to programming. With right pointer, I'll be able to carve out a solution. Someone just suggest me how to attack this problem.

The MySQL version I am using is:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Comment: What's your mysql version?did your mysql version support cte ?

Comment: @D-Shih, updated the original post with the details.

Comment: Would you consider let your mysql support `CTE`? because you need to make a calendar table. using `CTE` will be eazier

Comment: As long as the solution works, I won't mind. Could you offer a something that I can build upon?

Comment: I wrote a version for `cte recursive` @Sushant Vasishta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your mysql support `cte recursive` you can try to use it to make a calendar table.

Then do `outer join` and subquery with `case when`

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   ID int,
   Name varchar(50),
   SomeVal float,   
   OtherVal float,   
   `Date` date
);




insert into T values (10,'Somebody',33001.93,33001.93,'2018-10-01');
insert into T values (10,'Somebody',33481.93,33481.93,'2018-10-02');
insert into T values (10,'Somebody',33001.93,33001.93,'2018-10-03');
insert into T values (10,'Somebody',33582.76,33582.76,'2018-10-04');
insert into T values (10,'Somebody',33582.73,33582.79,'2018-10-05');
insert into T values (10,'Somebody',33582.76,33582.76,'2018-10-08');
insert into T values (10,'Somebody',33462.76,33462.76,'2018-10-10');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH recursive CTE as(
  SELECT MIN(Date) minDt,MAX(Date) maxDt
  FROM T
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date_add(minDt,INTERVAL 1 DAY),maxDt
  FROM CTE
  WHERE minDt < maxDt
)

SELECT  
    CASE WHEN ID IS NULL THEN (SELECT ID 
                            FROM T tt 
                            WHERE tt.Date < t1.minDt
                            ORDER BY tt.Date DESC
                            LIMIT 1)  
    ELSE ID END ID,
    CASE WHEN Name IS NULL THEN (SELECT Name 
                            FROM T tt 
                            WHERE tt.Date < t1.minDt
                            ORDER BY tt.Date DESC
                            LIMIT 1) 
    ELSE Name END Name,
    CASE WHEN SomeVal IS NULL THEN (SELECT SomeVal 
                            FROM T tt 
                            WHERE tt.Date < t1.minDt
                            ORDER BY tt.Date DESC
                            LIMIT 1) 
    ELSE SomeVal END SomeVal,
    CASE WHEN OtherVal IS NULL THEN (SELECT OtherVal 
                            FROM T tt 
                            WHERE tt.Date < t1.minDt
                            ORDER BY tt.Date DESC
                            LIMIT 1) 
    ELSE OtherVal END OtherVal,
    minDt
FROM CTE t1 
LEFT JOIN T t2 ON t1.minDt = t2.Date
ORDER BY t1.minDT;

| ID  | Name     | SomeVal        | OtherVal       | minDt      |
| --- | -------- | -------------- | -------------- | ---------- |
| 10  | Somebody | 33001.9296875  | 33001.9296875  | 2018-10-01 |
| 10  | Somebody | 33481.9296875  | 33481.9296875  | 2018-10-02 |
| 10  | Somebody | 33001.9296875  | 33001.9296875  | 2018-10-03 |
| 10  | Somebody | 33582.76171875 | 33582.76171875 | 2018-10-04 |
| 10  | Somebody | 33582.73046875 | 33582.7890625  | 2018-10-05 |
| 10  | Somebody | 33582.73046875 | 33582.7890625  | 2018-10-06 |
| 10  | Somebody | 33582.73046875 | 33582.7890625  | 2018-10-07 |
| 10  | Somebody | 33582.76171875 | 33582.76171875 | 2018-10-08 |
| 10  | Somebody | 33582.76171875 | 33582.76171875 | 2018-10-09 |
| 10  | Somebody | 33462.76171875 | 33462.76171875 | 2018-10-10 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5S3rMa48zw1vNYYdoSoquD/4)

---

If your mysql version didn't support `cte`,you can create a calendar table for `outer join`

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   ID int,
   Name varchar(50),
   SomeVal float,   
   OtherVal float,   
   `Date` date
);




insert into T values (10,'Somebody',33001.93,33001.93,'2018-10-01');
insert into T values (10,'Somebody',33481.93,33481.93,'2018-10-02');
insert into T values (10,'Somebody',33001.93,33001.93,'2018-10-03');
insert into T values (10,'Somebody',33582.76,33582.76,'2018-10-04');
insert into T values (10,'Somebody',33582.73,33582.79,'2018-10-05');
insert into T values (10,'Somebody',33582.76,33582.76,'2018-10-08');
insert into T values (10,'Somebody',33462.76,33462.76,'2018-10-10');


CREATE Table calendar(
   minDt Date
);

INSERT INTO calendar values ('2018-10-01');
INSERT INTO calendar values ('2018-10-02');
INSERT INTO calendar values ('2018-10-03');
INSERT INTO calendar values ('2018-10-04');
INSERT INTO calendar values ('2018-10-05');
INSERT INTO calendar values ('2018-10-06');
INSERT INTO calendar values ('2018-10-07');
INSERT INTO calendar values ('2018-10-08');
INSERT INTO calendar values ('2018-10-09');
INSERT INTO calendar values ('2018-10-10');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT  
    CASE WHEN ID IS NULL THEN (SELECT ID 
                            FROM T tt 
                            WHERE tt.Date < t1.minDt
                            ORDER BY tt.Date DESC
                            LIMIT 1)  
    ELSE ID END ID,
    CASE WHEN Name IS NULL THEN (SELECT Name 
                            FROM T tt 
                            WHERE tt.Date < t1.minDt
                            ORDER BY tt.Date DESC
                            LIMIT 1) 
    ELSE Name END Name,
    CASE WHEN SomeVal IS NULL THEN (SELECT SomeVal 
                            FROM T tt 
                            WHERE tt.Date < t1.minDt
                            ORDER BY tt.Date DESC
                            LIMIT 1) 
    ELSE SomeVal END SomeVal,
    CASE WHEN OtherVal IS NULL THEN (SELECT OtherVal 
                            FROM T tt 
                            WHERE tt.Date < t1.minDt
                            ORDER BY tt.Date DESC
                            LIMIT 1) 
    ELSE OtherVal END OtherVal,
    minDt
FROM calendar t1 
LEFT JOIN T t2 ON t1.minDt = t2.Date
ORDER BY t1.minDT;

| ID  | Name     | SomeVal        | OtherVal       | minDt      |
| --- | -------- | -------------- | -------------- | ---------- |
| 10  | Somebody | 33001.9296875  | 33001.9296875  | 2018-10-01 |
| 10  | Somebody | 33481.9296875  | 33481.9296875  | 2018-10-02 |
| 10  | Somebody | 33001.9296875  | 33001.9296875  | 2018-10-03 |
| 10  | Somebody | 33582.76171875 | 33582.76171875 | 2018-10-04 |
| 10  | Somebody | 33582.73046875 | 33582.7890625  | 2018-10-05 |
| 10  | Somebody | 33582.73046875 | 33582.7890625  | 2018-10-06 |
| 10  | Somebody | 33582.73046875 | 33582.7890625  | 2018-10-07 |
| 10  | Somebody | 33582.76171875 | 33582.76171875 | 2018-10-08 |
| 10  | Somebody | 33582.76171875 | 33582.76171875 | 2018-10-09 |
| 10  | Somebody | 33462.76171875 | 33462.76171875 | 2018-10-10 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5S3rMa48zw1vNYYdoSoquD/3)

Comment: Thanks @D-Shih It looks like you user MySQL ver 8 to write that. My version is 5.7. I get error while trying to follow the solution you offered.

More importantly, could you briefly elaborate the approach? I am new to SQL and your explanation would be critical in firming up my understanding about the utilization/ enhancing my capability to modify the solution.

Comment: The key point you need to make a  calendar table to fill up your date, which you are missing.

Comment: or you can create a calendar table for `outer join` here is a sample  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5S3rMa48zw1vNYYdoSoquD/2    @SushantVasishta

Comment: The table need to insert dates, which you want to use then `outer join` base on it.

Comment: Superb. I am just curious about this part: SELECT ID 
                            FROM T tt 
                            WHERE tt.Date < t1.minDt
                            ORDER BY tt.Date
                            LIMIT 1  For 6th Oct, why'd this just pull details from the 5th record on T? If the sequence of date changes in T, this particular snippet could prospectively fetch another record (any record where date value is less than 6th Oct) @D-Shih

Comment: This subquery can help you get the last date which mean  get last available row, BTW I find you need to use  `ORDER BY tt.Date DESC` and I modify my answer :)

Comment: Wanted to explicitly thank you @D-Shih The solution is really simple and pulled off quite nicely. I should be able to think like that.